# Why is the Friedel-Crafts alkylation of nitrobenzene disfavoured?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, aromatic-compounds

> Suggest a synthetic route to *m*-nitrotoluene, starting from benzene.

The conversion can be achieved in two ways:

$\hspace{10 mm}$[image: Route 1]

or:

[image]

However, the first route is not possible as the Friedel-Crafts reaction does not yield a meta-substituted product. Why is that so?

Comment: Hmm, I don't like second reaction either, you have proof it would work?

Comment: Also, I don't believe Na will leave that nitro group intact.

Comment: The use of a methyl halide does not seem feasible to me, as it suggests that the electrophile would be a methyl carbocation, which does not form in practicality. I would imagine otherwise that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The nitro group is so deactivating that yields are really poor for Friedel-Crafts reactions with nitrobenzene; not even the *meta*-substituted product is found in good yield. In fact, nitrobenzene is actually [used as a solvent in Friedel-Crafts reactions](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bscb.19660750903/abstract).

Comment: Agreed. Most undergraduate organic chemistry texts come with a big disclaimer that Friedel-Crafts reactions work poorly on deactivated rings. I would love to see a link or reference for the use of nitrobenzene as a solvent for FC reactions. It would really solidify this answer.

Comment: @BenNorris http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bscb.19660750903/abstract